# Serve up Captcha to user in Webbrowser in Windows Form

Tags: c#, html, screen-scraping, captcha

I'm writing an app to automate a search for flights on an airline webpage. Unfortunately, it uses a serious captcha. . . The automated process is not very involved, and doesn't run very quickly, but doing the search manually and writing down the prices is very laborious.

I would like to keep my automated code, but when the page is redirected to a Captcha (something that happens after every 10 requests or so), I want to serve the Captcha up in a Webform in a webbrowser, allow the user to read the Captcha, enter the text and hit 'Continue'. It's not much faster than doing the whole thing manually, but it is easier!

Unfortunately, I cannot get the Captcha image to render in a webbrowser. In fact, I can't even see it in Fiddler when I run through the web requests manually.

Any ideas about how I can display the Captcha in a Windows form? Once the user can see it, I can continue with creating the webrequests and postdata as usual.

Would appreciate any help at all.

Thanks.

Comment: You might try having your application download the captcha using the session it is already attached to, and display the image in an Image window.  Saves you having to load it into a WB control, unless you were already using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw one like this on a county court site recently. The IMG was a GET request, but if requested it directly it wouldn't work. It turned out the request for the image needed a cookie. In my case I updated HTTPClient to accommodate it.